# Alta HR disconnects after syncing Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

When opening the Fitbit app in Windows 10, Alta HR connects, syncs, then disconnects. I'd like to keep it connected via BT to send notifications to the Alta HR. How do I fix this?

Comment: You want Alta HR notifications to appear on your desktop machine?

Comment: @spikey_richie Windows 10 notifications go to the Alta HR, but they have to be constantly connected in order for this to work.

Comment: I don't believe it's designed to work this way. Fitbit devices are quite limited in the notification types they can show. You might be better off asking this on the Fitbit community page https://community.fitbit.com/t5/Community/ct-p/EN

Comment: @spikey_richie I'm not focusing on notifications. I'm focusing on trying to get it constantly connected to Windows 10 as it did in iPadOS.